# How to get the particular value from the response message and assign it to another variable in the next request in Jmeter?

Tags: android, api, jmeter, chat, performance-testing

I am trying to make a performance testing process by using the Jmeter for the mobile chat application. The scenario i am trying is,need to analyze the output during the N number of new user registration process.I am feeding the N user data through "CSV Data Set Config".In that mentioned the variable names as "phone,ime".

For each new user registration process,the application will generate the one time password when calling the API1.**The question is,I need to get that generated one time password from the API1 response message for each phone user and need to assign the value to the variable ${code} when calling the API2**.

The below are the API & parameters details:

API1:`/api/users/registration-sms.html?`
1) Name:phone, Value:   ${phone}
2) Name:ime, Value:   ${ime}
Example : 
Request - POST data: phone=917010370002 & ime=e78b56418b55b32c
Response:`{"response":{"httpCode":200,"Message":"True","Code":"5858"}}`

API2: `/api/users/registration-sms-verfy.html?`
1) Name:phone, Value:${phone}
2) Name:code, Value:${code}
**Note : For this variable ${code},We need to get the data from the API1("Code":"5858") response message for the respective phone(917010370002).**

Please provide me the feasible solution to sort out of my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular extractor post processor like,

Assuming your response is like

```
{"response":{"httpCode":200,"Message":"True","Code":"5858"}}
```

your regular expression will be like to extract code value but for specifiic phone no you need to modify it a little bit,

```
"Code"\:"(\d+)"
```

for occurance detail you can provide which match no. you want.

Refer [Regular Expression Exctrator Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Comment: Thank you so much for your speedy answers. It is helped me a lot.But I am facing the following issue when calling the API2.(i.e) Receiving only the Not Found value.POST data: phone=917010370010&code=NOT FOUND. My regular expression is as follows, Reference Name : code, Regular Expression:"code"\:"(\d+)", Template:$1$, Match No:1,Default Value : NOT FOUND. Expecting you reply. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post your complete reply, so that I can validate/modify regex accordingly?

Comment: Thank you for your speedy responses. API 1: api/users/registration-sms.html?  
Request is POST data:
phone=917010370003&ime=e78b56418b55b33c&country=91&gcm= ,Response data is {"response":{"httpCode":200,"Message":"True","Code":"7491"}} API2: /api/users/registration-sms-verfy.html? Request is 
POST data:
phone=917010370003&code=NOT FOUND, Response is {"response":{"httpCode":"200","Message":"True"}}. The issue is when calling the API2 the code variable value is not getting from API1 responded value (i.e) 7491. Please check and do the needful.

Comment: I could find it in response field without any error. check whether are you trying to extract the value before response has received (I mean try inserting delay between request and regex extractor)

Comment: Same issue even added the constant timer up to 1000

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your script? (if its not confidential)

Comment: Give me your email id so that i will share you the whole script screen s as ppt.

Comment: nachiket.kate@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Nachiket,I have sent the script screenshots and sample data to your email account. Please check it and do the needful.

Comment: Just i corrected the regular expression value first word character as capital letter (i.e) "Code"\:"(\d+)" because in the response message the "code" word first character mentioned as capital letter. Just i tried.Now its working correctly.So the thing is,regular expression fields are case sensitive. Thank you for your timely support.